# Java - JNativeHook - getKeyText

Tags: java

With JNativeHook you can use `NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(ev.getKeyCode())` to get a String from a the key code, but this is really annoying since, stuff like [space] and [.] will literally show up as "Space" and "Dot", is there anyway to just get the character?

Thank alot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the key typed event.  That event will return that actual char produced by the key event for the native language and context.  `NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(...)` is generally only used to get a textual representation of the key for things like logging.  If you really want to change the key returned by `getKeyText`, you may override the AWT property for the particular key.  For example, starting java with `-DAWT.space="TheSpaceBar!"` will return "TheSpaceBar!" for `VC_SPACE`.  I am sure Java lists these properties somewhere, but I have no idea where so just read the src at [github](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/master/src/java/org/jnativehook/keyboard/NativeKeyEvent.java#L621).